# Consume Webservice JAX with JSP

Tags: java, web-services, wsdl, jax-ws

Hello i have a little question, well i am new on webservice and i am trying to consume a webservice which returns an xml structure, but i only want the String result, this is the method for take the result

```
public JAXBElement<ResultLogin> getResultLogin() {
        return resultLogin;
    }
```

i return it on String parsing it with `toString();` but only returns a strange code not the true result.

Any tips? or tutorials or something?  Ty

Comment: please show more code. It is not clear what JSP has to do with this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess the problem is that you are invoking the `toString()` method on the JAXBElement object returned. Instead, what you need to do is to get the value out of the JAXBElement, cast it to a `ResultLogin` object and invoke `toString()` on it:

```
((ResultLogin) getResultLogin().getValue()).toString();
```